# Silent install of MySQL using NSIS

Tags: mysql, nsis, windows-installer, silent-installer

I'm trying to install MySQL silently using NSIS. Right now I'm just trying to get the MySQL part down, the script is purely for installing MySQL.

The majority of the forum posts I've read are from 2009-2011, so I would imagine out of date.

So far I have this basic script:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!include WordFunc.nsh
!insertmacro VersionCompare
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include InstallOptions.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Name "sqltest"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT

OutFile "sqltest.exe"
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\sqltest"
RequestExecutionLevel admin

XPStyle on


!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "The MySQL Test Install"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
;!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
;!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"



Section "install"
    File mysql.msi
    ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\mysql.msi" /qn'
    SetOutPath "$PROGRAMFILES\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7.15"

SectionEnd
```

As you can see all I do is ask the MSI to run silently and specify the install folder.

When I build the NSIS installer and run it the folder `$PROGRAMFILES\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7.15` appears but nothing is inside it.

I am sure there is something else I have to run but nothing I have tried results in an actual install.

Any pointers would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `SetOutPath` instruction **before** `File` instructions because it sets the destination path for extracted files.

You normally do `SetOutPath "$InstDir"` before extracting files...

Comment: I'll give that a go. That does make perfect sense, I was just following another example to get to that stage

Comment: I swapped the msiexec and SetOutPath around and still the folder appears to be blank. The MSI doesn't appear to be installing

Comment: `SetOutPath` needs to be the first instruction in the `Section`! `SetOutPath` then `File` then `ExecWait`! Your `SetOutPath` line contains some hardcoded path that might not be the same as $InstDir, use the same path in both `SetOutPath` and `ExecWait`!